# Generate xaml file (page) at runtime and reference it with uri

Tags: xaml, uri, xamlwriter

Im working on a wpf application based on Modern UI that have a gui designer part where the user can add and then drag/drop/resize etc. the control. The properties for the controls position, size etc. is stored in a table in a database. There are several pages where the user can place the controls.

What I have:
On application start the controls are positioned on a canvas on a page (xaml file) based on a page id. Those pages are all in the project when I compile.

What I want:
I need a way to dynamically instantiate those pages and to be able to referens each one with an uri.

What I have tried:
I have tried to have a "template page" and instantiate each new page from there. I then position the controls on it. Then i use xamlwriter.save to create a xaml file that I hope to be able to reference with a Uri.
But I fail when I try to reference the xaml file.

If you can help me with my solution or if there is a better way, please enlighten me.

Best regards,
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot reference dynamically generated pages with an URI then you could use one (or more, maybe a pool of) built-in page(s) that is/are part of your project. On that page you could have a content control with a data template that is set dynamically. Here is some code that demonstrates this:

The XAML for the placeholder page:

```
<Window 
    x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl x:Name="mainContent" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The code behind for this demo:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mainContent.ContentTemplate = GenerateDataTemplate();
        }

        public DataTemplate GenerateDataTemplate()
        {
            StringBuilder xamlTemplate = new StringBuilder();

            xamlTemplate.Append("<DataTemplate");
            xamlTemplate.Append("   xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"");
            xamlTemplate.Append("   xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\">");
            xamlTemplate.Append("      <TextBlock Text=\"This is a test\" FontSize=\"40\" Foreground=\"Red\" />");
            xamlTemplate.Append("</DataTemplate>");

            return (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(GenerateStreamFromString(xamlTemplate.ToString()));
        }

        private MemoryStream GenerateStreamFromString(string value)
        {
            return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value ?? ""));
        }
    }
}
```